# Button suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

Hi I had a button on the website I am developing that was working fine, then I added some styling and bootstrap to the webpage yesterday and today it isn't working. The logic all looks fine so I'm not sure what could be going wrong.

I have an event handler in my page_load pointing to a valid function, but for some reason the function is not called when I click on the button:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendButton.Click += new EventHandler(SendButton_Click);
    //Some other code I have left out for simplicity
}
public void SendButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserCredential sendingUser = (UserCredential)Session["authenticatedUser"];
    UserCredential receivingUser = Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(Session["receivinguserid"]));
    Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == (int)sendingUser.UserID).Conversations.Find(t => t.ReceivingUserID == receivingUser.UserID).ReadMessageList.Add(new Message(MessageTextBox.Text, (int)sendingUser.UserID, DateTime.Now));
    Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == (int)receivingUser.UserID).Conversations.Find(t => t.ReceivingUserID == sendingUser.UserID).UnReadMessageList.Add(new Message(MessageTextBox.Text, (int)sendingUser.UserID, DateTime.Now));
    ChatLabel.Text += "<br>" + sendingUser.Name.ToString() + ": " + MessageTextBox.Text + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMMM HH:mm");
    MessageTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

And here is my html page, the SendButton being all the way at the bottom:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well center" style="width:50%">
            <a>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server">
                </asp:Timer>
            </a>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tim" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="tim" Interval="5000" Enabled="true" OnTick="UpdateChat" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label ID="ChatLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:TextBox ID="MessageTextBox" runat="server" Width="438px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClientClick="return false"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Use F12 on IE and see if your DOMis the same as before, didn't you change some IDs or class?

Comment: Why are you wiring up the event handler in your Page_Load? Why not set it  declaratively on the button? And why are you returning false `OnClientClick`? Seems like that would prevent a postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove or clear `OnClientClick="return false"` of the button.

If a (client side) javascript button handler returns `false` then the entire Form won't ever be submitted, so your server side code will never be reached.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember adding that in, but it works great